# Where can we find reference of the story of Holika burning instead of Prahlada?

Tags: puranas, reference-request, prahlada

I have checked some of the places where the story of Prahlada-Nrisimhadev-Hiranyakashipu is mentioned, for eg: in the Narasimha Purana, the [Srimad Bhagavatam](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/5/) and Vishnu Purana for a mention of Hiranyakashipu's sister Holika, but I failed to find the [popular story of Holika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holika) who sits taking Prahald on her lap and instead of Prahlad herself gets burnt.

Though I found in [Vishnu Purana, 1.18](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp053.htm) that the Daitya Brahmanas produced Mantra-agni (KRtyA) to burn Prahlad but instead they themselves got into danger and Prahlad saved them.

So I would like to know whether this story has a basis in any of the Maha-Puranas or Upa-Puranas or may be some Sthal Purana or when did the story first appear and where?

Comment: I think it's a folklore. Because Hiranyakashipu's sister is Simhika, who later slayed by Hanuman and the name "Holika" was never mentioned in any Puranas.